# ForgetPassword page content not showing after @Url.Action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a button that, when clicked, will open a page that allows the user to change their password.

I have a button that, when clicked, redirects to the action "ForgetPassword" in the controller "Account":

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ForgetPassword", "Account")">Forgot password?</a>
```

However, when clicked, nothing changes but the URL, which becomes https://localhost:44377/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fForgetPassword

I also put a breakpoint on the action but it is never hit.

The entire controller is marked with [AllowAnonymous].
The web.config file features these lines

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

I expect from this functionality for the content of the page "ForgetPassword" to be shown.

What can I do to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have authentication on that forgotten password page - looks like it's redirecting you to the login page.  You probably have the `Authorize` attribute on the account controller, if so you would need to add the `AllowAnonymous` attribute to the forgot password action

Comment: @Pete You are right. He added authentication for the forgot page.

Comment: @Pete The entire controller allows Anonymous

Comment: @Jai248 Thats an assumption.

The entire controller is [AllowAnonymous]

Comment: @CitrusBoy there is something that is forcing that action to authenticate otherwise it wouldn't redirect to the login page

Comment: @Pete Im not quite sure what it is then. There is no sign of auth in the account controller